# Mongoose connectio occured MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to cluster0-shard-00-01-utzss.mongodb.net:27017 closed error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Mongoose default connection is disconnected
Mongoose default connection has occured MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to cluster0-shard-00-01-utzss.mongodb.net:27017 closed error
(node:8421) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to cluster0-shard-00-01-utzss.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/media/tyro/6250439650437039/Work Space/Web/JS-Learning/node-restfulApi-shop/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/conn
ection/connection.js:352:9)
```

.

```
 const dbURL  = 'mongodb+srv://node-rest-shop:node-rest-shop@cluster0-utzss.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
 mongoose.connect(dbURL,{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });
 mongoose.connection.on('connected', function(){
    console.log("Mongoose default connection is open to ", dbURL);
  });
 mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err){
     console.log("Mongoose default connection has occured "+err+" error");
 });
 mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function(){
     console.log("Mongoose default connection is disconnected");
 });
```

Comment: this is because there was an error - what is your question? Don't just dump out an error in your title and question, along with a tiny bit of code and expect anyone to know what you are asking

Comment: how to solved this type or error?

Comment: You probably need to  white-list your IP address under Clusters -> security -> IP Whitelist

Comment: i used my own ip and also used 0.0.0.0/0 , still got same error.